# Show all NSWindows

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nswindow, osx-tiger

Pretty simple idea here, I want to show all the NSWindows in an app. The idea being that there are two windows in the app, one his hidden the other is vissable. I want to show all the windows in the app and then hide one. I can hide the window I want to hide but I cant show the windows because I am unable to obtain a reference to it. is there anyway of getting a list of all the nswindows in the app then iterating through it and hiding them or something similar, I can use [NSApp windows] however trying to use

```
NSArray *windowArray = [NSApp windows];
[windowArray[0] makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
[NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
```

does not work, nor does:

```
NSArray *windowArray = [NSApp windows];
NSWindow *tempWindow = windowArray[0];
[tempWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
[NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
```

any suggestions?

Comment: It depends on whether you have xib files or window controllerers + view controllers to house windows.  It is also unclear whether or not you have multiple xib files or storyboards.

Comment: its using a single nib file (this being xcode 2.5) with two nswindows in it

Comment: I only suppose that windowArray really contains references to all existing windows in your xib file.  Then shouldn't it be something like for 

(NSWindow *win in windowArray) {
    [win setIsVisible = YES];
}

?  I won't test it myself since I no longer write Objective-C.

Comment: How do you hide the window?

Comment: [menuWindow OrderOut:self]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well in hindsight I've been a bit stupid. I had two seep rate controller objects each running one window. One was hardly doing anything as the view inside it was being handled by a different object so I just removed that one and made the first controller object take care of both windows. Problem solved.